# cloth simulation has a forcefield around object

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I have a basic T-shirt which I want to place on my human character. However, after running the simulation, I find that the T-shirt seems to float above my character and not collide with it's shoulders as I expect it to.

I have looked quite abit into the `Stiffness` properties and the `Pin Groups` properties to see if any of those could be causing the problem. I haven't been able to identify any of them as the cause.

What is causing my cloth to float instead of collide?

Here is the download link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X8es7nkDdXzSUkNNSL66-OBPwhzUtGS7/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because a distance set for simulation and collider.

In Cloth setting (it is ok in your file):

[image]

In collider (it is to big in your file):

[image]

You can decrease these values, but setting it close to 0 may cause varios errors.